# Laravel 4: Pagination always returning null

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

According to the [Laravel 4 paginations docs page](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination), this should be providing me with pagination.

I have 3 returned results for this query:

```
$florist = Florist::all();
```

I paginate it:

```
$florist = Florist::paginate(1);
```

And in my view I have added:

```
{{ $florist->links }}
```

Yet nothing is displayed. If I do a `var_dump` of `$florist->links` it always returns `null`. Changing the pagination number in the query makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you pass `$florist' to the view?

Comment: `return View::make('florists')->with('florist', $florist);`

Answer (score 1):

`links` is not a property but a method. To print out the links you need to call that method.

```
{{ $florist->links() }}
```

Comment: Using `links` as a method gives an undefined method error.

Comment: @Valency What do you get if you do a `var_dump` on `$florist`? Is it an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`?

Comment: It looks like a dump of the model, but I also see 'perPage', so it might be the Paginator. Sorry, I'm quite new to this. This is the output: http://pastebin.com/TbRGfqDH

Comment: @Valency That's an instance of Eloquent. Are you sure you're calling the `paginate` method to retrieve the data?

Comment: `Florist` is an Eloquent model and I am calling `paginate(1)` on it. I have no `links` method of my own and it's returning null instead of undefined, so I'm assuming that the pagination helper is being included somewhere.

Comment: And you're sure you didn't modify the value of the variable in any way? I find this odd, since `paginate` should return an instance of the paginator and not the eloquent model.

Comment: That's all that's in the controller. I make the query and then pass it through to the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56245/discussion-between-kemal-fadillah-and-valency).